# Is there a simple web GUI for Apache that runs on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, administration, webmin

Sadly, all the answers that Google turns up seem to be way out of date ([Rapache](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Rapache) for example no longer runs on Ubuntu it seems).

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) with a [Lubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) interface, for testing purposes, and I just want a simple, straightforward GUI that will allow me (for example) to switch modules on and off, create and delete virtual servers, and the like.

Webmin looks nice, but does it run on Ubuntu? Or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 5):

Webmin is still available for Ubuntu even if it's not shipped with the default applications or repositories.

1. Edit the source file:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webmin.list
   ```
2. Add this line into the end:

   ```
   deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
   ```
3. Download and install the key:

   ```
   wget -q http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
4. Update the software list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. Install Webmin:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install webmin
   ```

Finally, in your client’s web browser, go to the webmin login page, https://localhost:10000.

#### HINT

If you don't want to add the repository you can just download the `.deb` by clicking [this](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.750_all.deb).

Now you can install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i webmin*.deb
```